# Output Request Variables to text file

Tags: php, variables, text, output, fwrite

IN PHP
For some reason I the text file is blank except the rare occasion that someone sends a fake WP hack to it.

Here is my code it should sum up what I am trying.

```
$f = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'-'.date('h-i');
$j = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $j;
file_put_contents($f.'.txt', $j);
```

I have tried to use fwrite as well as used the foreach.  It prints just fine on the screen.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Not seeing any errors.  This creates a unique file each visit, file_append is to append to the same file.  I forgot to mention it is using SSL

Comment: The issue has to do with the site being ssl.  is there anything that can be done about that